# Restricting the range of $x$ to normalize the wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization

I have a system in nuclear physics which can be approximated by two coupled harmonic oscillators (the Hamiltonian is a bit peculiar though.) I will denote their spatial coordinates by $x$ and $y$.

I would like to normalize the wavefunction for the state where the $y$-oscillator (i.e. the oscillator whose spatial coordinate I am denoting by $y$) is in the ground state and the $x$-oscillator is in the $n$-th state,
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx\, \psi_{n,0}^*(x,y)\psi_{n,0}(x,y)=1.$$
The integral over $y$ converges and gives
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dy\, \psi_{n,0}^*(x,y)\psi_{n,0}(x,y) =  e^{\gamma}+\cos \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}-4 \alpha  x \Omega \right).$$
Here $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants that depend on the oscillator frequencies and the coupling constant $C$, and $\Omega$ is the frequency of the $x$-oscillator.

The integral over $x$ over all space obviously diverges because of the $\cos \left(4 \alpha \Omega x-n \pi/2\right)$ term. So I am wondering if there are any approximations or cut-offs that I can make to limit the range of the variable $x$ in order to be able to normalize the wavefunction.

Comment: $y$ is not in a ground state: it’s a coordinate.  Do you mean the second particle is in the ground state?  If your $\psi$ depends on $x$ and $y$ then you have not decoupled your system and so having one particle in a ground state but not the other is unclear.

Comment: If you've performed the definite integral over $y$, then there cannot be $y$'s in the result, are those supposed to be $x$'s?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero in this context, by $y$ I mean the oscillator whose spatial coordinate is denoted by $y$.

Comment: @Triatticus thanks for pointing this out, I had copied the wrong equation!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think more information about the system and its Hamiltonian will be needed. Otherwise, these just look like non-normalizable states, which means that it's not so similar to a harmonic oscillator.